# Как добавить ID пользователя в свою таблицу при его регистрации в MODx

Tags: pdo, modx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, куда чего нужно дописать, чтобы ID новосозданного пользователя добавлялся в поле собственной таблицы? Предполагаю, что нужно где-то в файле процессора создания пользователя дописать строки со связями с этой таблицей. И в модель изменения нужно внести. Но вот докумекать пока не могу, где именно эти изменения сделать. Дайте наводку или на водку, пожалуйста))

Comment: Что-то менять в файлах отвечающих за регистрацию или любых других "не ваших" скриптах - весьма плохая практика. Любое обновление или откат версии и вы всё теряете (это если из очевидных минусов). По вашему вопросу, наводку - надо вешать плагин на событие `OnUserSave` и в нём проводить необходимые манипуляции с вашей таблицей и данными юзера.

Comment: Об этих минусах мне всё понятно, но я таки написал пару строк в register.php, которые можно будет добавить после обновления ядра, добавил класс объектов. А вот про наводку на событие OnUserSave - большое спасибо. Как-то мне в голову не пришло. Надо бы подучить плагины. Их я ещё почти не касался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Создайте плагин и повесьте на него событие **OnUserSave**:

```
switch ($modx->event->name) {
    case 'OnUserSave':
        // проверяем, новый ли пользователь
        if ($mode == 'new') {
            // получаем id пользователя
            $id = $user->get('id');
            // записываем полученный id в свою таблицу
            $myTable = $modx->newObject('MyTableObject');
            $myTable->set('user_id', $id);
            $myTable->save();
        }
    break;
}
```

*естественно, для взаимодействия со своими таблицами необходимо создать модель*